# Discords Bots Spesific Tags

Tags: python, bots, discord

```
 await message.channel.send('Hey, @TheCrimsonborn#9975! What's up Master!'.format(message))
```

This is my normal reply codes. But my Bot doesn't tag me. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not clear what your question is. Please [edit] your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanted to tag whoever ran the command you use `<@message.author.id>`
If you want it to always tag you use `<@Your User ID>`